# Как перенести ограничения пользователя на другой Пк?

Tags: windows, group-policy

Я сделал для пользователя "Test" ограничения в локальной групповой политике через оснастку mmc, представленные ниже и сохранил этот конфиг в формате .msc
Теперь ломаю голову над тем как перенести все эти ограничения для конкретного пользователя на другие пк, с таким же именем пользователя.

Пробовал конфиг просто открыть на другом компе, комп пишет недостаточно прав, хотя я открывал с правами админа (видимо в пути проблема).
Пробовал полностью перекинуть папку с пользователем из Users, не прокатило, ограничения не перенеслись.
Пробовал также через cmd: secedit /export /cfg  c:\sec.cfg /areas USER_RIGHTS /user Test (здесь видимо проблема в синтаксисе)

Какие есть способы для активации этих ограничений? В ручную на 300 компах делать это не хочется

[image: Ограничения в mmc]